# What does the assembly code statement: cmp %eax,<hexadecimal>(<register>,<register>,4) mean?

Tags: assembly, att

Specifically, there is a compare statement which says:

```
cmp    %eax, 0xc(%esp, %esi, 4)
```

and then a jump if not equal statement after it. I want to know what the latter part of the statement `0xc(%esp,%esi,4)` is referring to.

Thanks!

Comment: AT&T syntax strikes again!

Answer (score 1):

In AT&T syntax, memory operands have the format

```
displacement(base register, offset register, scalar multiplier)
```

In Intel syntax, `cmp %eax,0xc(%esp,%esi,4)` (shouldn't that be `cmpl` by the way?) would be written as `cmp [esp + esi * 4 + 12], eax` making it visible what role all the parts play.

Comment: ["If no suffix is specified by an instruction then as tries to fill in the missing suffix based on the destination register operand (the last one by convention)"](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html). And vice versa ;-)

Comment: @rkhb how can there be a vice versa? Does the suffix override the operand size?

Comment: I meant *"...based on the source register operand (the first one..."*. I guess it's a concession to "modern" assembly programming. If the operand size can be determined "anyhow", a suffix isn't needed. I remember no case where a suffix can override that assumption, but I don't know every cpu architecture.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmp %eax,0xc(%esp,%esi,4)
```

is the same as this:

```
cmp [esp + 12 + 4*esi], eax
```

The formula in the the brackets calculates the address. The value saved at that address is compared with `eax`.

Comment: Aren't the operands swapped though?

Comment: @harold: Yeah, my fault.and I mixed up mov and cmp as well. I edit it. at&t should simply die out please...